# What are other words or phrases for "total catch", "whole package", or "perfect 10" when referring to an attractive bachelorette?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I've found it difficult to search for synonyms.

I'm hoping for some noun that signifies a really impressive woman that any man would want to share life with.

"Perfect 10" and "bombshell" are probably too focused on physical appearance than I'm intending. "Eligible bachelorette" is too clunky.

I lead a group of women who are single and looking for a male life partner. These women are amazing: successful, fit, attractive, and intelligent. And they're actively dating--hoping to find their match.

And our tribe wants a name!  We'd love to call ourselves The ______s* and say that our weekly group call is The _______ Hour, or something like that.

*plural variation of the word or phrase I'm asking for

Comment: Is the term you're looking for gender-specific? That is, could a group of men also use the single word?

Comment: This question comes with assumptions:  1) There exists *a woman* that *any* man would want to "share [their?] life with"...  2) That if one or more such women exist, they would be "successful, fit, attractive, and intelligent."  3) That these "amazing" women do exist, and have grouped together the better to find their mates.  Yet '1)' is held to be a *good thing*, that these women must be desired by all, but are themselves extremely particular, which seems both inconvenient for their mostly useless admirers, who by virtue of their numbers become obstructive to these women's search...

Comment: @JEL The term I'm looking for would probably be best if it's gender-specific (i.e. refers to women only) because that would make it clearer / more self-descriptive. Thanks.

Comment: @agc I'm not sure I understand your comment... although I can try to restate the question to see if we're removing what you're calling "assumptions". I could ask "What is a term that indicates a well-rounded, attractive, single/unpaired woman?"

Comment: (Sorry if my comment was unclear, I ran out of time, but unwisely posted it anyway.)   Perhaps the question is over-general, and might be narrowed by making the implicit more explicit to clarify how relevant the economic, social, & cultural standing of the men sought is, and how much that weighs against the men's health, morals, manners, and habits.

Comment: Dreamgirl or Dream Woman. That might be the best I've come up with so far. Others that recently caught my eye: Ms. Right, ladylove, main squeeze, dreamboat, peach, total babe, fox, hot number, head-turner, eye-candy, temptress. But most of these focus too narrowly and don't convey "total package". Dream Woman isn't quite good enough (especially since it's a common term rather than a proprietary name I've invented), but it's an example of a title that could bridge the present feeling of "I'm a catch" with the future feeling of "I'm my best self and living my dreams with my dream man".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ***goddess***, implying a person approaching perfection and probably widely desirable? If that seems too presumptuous, then something less grand such as ***princess*** might work. Yes, *princess* is sometimes used in a derogatory fashion, esp. in AmEng, but we could go on with *enchantress*, or, largely lacking gender, a *romantic*.

Comment: Thanks! Those are good ideas. Maybe going in that direction would work.

Comment: "Princess" does not play out well in some places, especially New York.

Comment: Yes, a couple of other terms popped into my head and I edited, knowing of Gandalf's observation in much of the U.S. but romanticizing the good points that possessors of charms might wish to promote in search of their optimal partner.